# Query SteamIDs for presence of an avatar

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table `vanrust_corev2.tblPlayerLog` that has approx 6.7k records,
I also have a table in a different database `vanrust_forum.tblPlayerAvatars` which has approx 6.7k records.

The purpose of this script is to pull the `SteamID` of players who don't have an avatar stored for them yet. However the issue here is, the execution time of this script is often 29-31 seconds which seemed a little strange to me as I'm sure there are much more sophisticated and larger databases that would not have this issue.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
vanrust_corev2.tblPlayerLog log
WHERE
not exists(
SELECT 
a.SteamID
FROM vanrust_forum.tblPlayerAvatars a
WHERE a.Steamid = log.SteamID)
```

This is for the same user, just to a different database.

This script works perfectly the only issue here is execution time so I'm hoping for some pointers on where I could be going wrong.

Here is the execution plan:

[image: exec-plan]

Comment: Please update your title to reflect what your code does.

Comment: I think the fact you are querying across two different servers has something to do with it. Hard to say without seeing the execution plan, though.

Comment: Hey, it's the same user/server, just a different database - does this make a difference ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Your query looks fine, it's probably something else. Can you post the execution plan with it? Just take a screenshot of it and attach it as a picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### I normally wouldn't recommend this, but...

According to your query execution plan, it is doing 22719171 table scans in order to fetch the next row. What I *think* the problem stems from is querying across databases, which may have to open a connection for each `Handler_read_rnd_next`, then close the connection each time. One way or the other, if your columns are properly indexed, something like this shouldn't take near that long. I think something about the setup is causing the optimizer to go into a loop across two databases, and SQL is not good at looping. To make this more set-based, I'd suggest pulling your data sets into one of the two databases with a construct like a temp table:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS vanrust_corev2.users_with_avatars;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vanrust_corev2.users_with_avatars (SteamID INT NOT NULL);
  INSERT INTO vanrust_corev2.users_with_avatars (SteamId) VALUES
    SELECT 
      a.SteamID
    FROM vanrust_forum.tblPlayerAvatars a
COMMIT;
```

Then, you could simply join the record sets within the `vanrust_corev2` database. This would increase I/O for a bit, but likely remove the need to connect between 2 databases millions of times while it does table scans:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
vanrust_corev2.tblPlayerLog log
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 
  a.SteamID
  FROM vanrust_corev2.users_with_avatars a
  WHERE a.Steamid = log.SteamID
);
```

And of course it's a good idea to `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE vanrust_corev2.users_with_avatars;` when you are done, although it will otherwise automatically drop when the session is ended with the database.

---

On another note, I strongly recommend you start naming aliases in a way that describes what they represent. `log` is OK, but `a` doesn't seem to mean anything.